Reconstructing graph given the set of second neighbors
Let $G = (V, E)$ be a simple undirected graph with $V = \{1, \ldots, n\}$ the set of each vertex. Let $d = \{ \deg(v) \mid v \in V \}$ the degree of each vertex and $s = \{ \{v, v'\} 
\subseteq \binom{V}{2} \mid v, v' \text{ are second neighbors} \}$ where $v, v'$ are second neighbors iff $\exists v'', \{v, v''\}, \{v', v''\} \in E$.
Can I reconstruct the graph $G$ starting from $d$ and $s$?
More precisely, does it hold that every graph $\bar G$ whose degree and set of second neighborhoods agree with $d$ and $s$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Take the complete graph on $a,b,c,d,e,f$ and make

$G_1$ by removing $(a,b), (a,c), (b, c), (d,e)$
$G_2$ by removing $(a,b), (a, c), (b, d), (c, e)$

Each vertex has the same degrees in both, and all points in both have full second neighbourhoods.
This is because all points have an edge to $f$, so $f$ is an intermediate point connecting two non-$f$ vertices. But every vertex has an edge to at least one non-$f$ vertex, which is an intermediate vertex connecting it to $f$.
$G_1$ and $G_2$ cannot be isomorphic because their complements are not isomorphic (the complement of $G_1$ has $3$ connected components, the complement of $G_2$ has $2$).

Technically the complement of $G_2$ isn't connected, because of the $f$ vertex. It would be more precise to say "the complement of $G_2$ contains $2$ disjoint subgraphs, while the complement of $G_1$ contains $3$".

@DanielP thanks, I've corrected it.

@ZoeAllen Thank you! Is there any piece of information that allows a correct reconstruction (except for the neighbourhood of each vertex of course)?

@incud : Very, very unlikely.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_property#Graph_invariants_and_graph_isomorphism
